# Write output to file in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I need to print a table column out to a text file in postgres, just a simple SELECT "column_name" FROM "table." I'm pretty sure there is a way to do this but I can't remember the syntax.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`COPY`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html).

If you need to copy an entire table, you can specify a table name:

```
COPY country TO '/usr1/proj/bray/sql/country_data';
```

You can also copy a query result:

```
COPY (SELECT column_name FROM country WHERE country_name LIKE 'A%')
TO   '/usr1/proj/bray/sql/a_list_countries.copy';
```

The same syntax can be used to *import* a table:

```
COPY country FROM '/usr1/proj/bray/sql/country_data';
```

It is possible to specify additional options, e.g. delimiters, format, etc. In my daily work, I often use:

```
COPY country TO '/usr1/proj/bray/sql/country_data' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

For a full description of the `COPY` statement, refer to the linked documentation page above.